# Los datos del arreglo desaparecen - Firebase (realtime database)

Tags: firebase

Mi consulta es sencilla pero no lo he podido solucionar. Por una extraña razón al llenar un arreglo a través del ciclo `ref.on` de `firebase`, si imprimo los datos del arreglo dentro de este ciclo, si aparecen, pero fuera de este ciclo, no reconoce los datos, y al hacer `console.log` me los muestra vacío. Aquí un código de ejemplo para que se entienda:

```
var firebase = conectarFirebase();
const db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref("eventos");
var arreglo = [];

ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot){
        var value = snapshot.val();
        var key = snapshot.key;
        arreglo.value.push({
          'title': value.nombre_evento,
          'start': value.fecha_inicio
      });
console.log(arreglo[0].title) //titulo1
}); 
console.log(arreglo[0].title) //undefinited
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español, te invito a que hagas el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así ganes tu primera [medalla!](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Answer (score 2):

te explico las llamadas a Firebase son asíncronos (también conocidas como “funciones en segundo plano”) mediante la generación de una promesa de JavaScript. Por lo que tu al ejecutar la linea de `ref.on(...)` se va a la siguiente linea `console.log(arreglo[0].title) //undefinited` y como arreglo todavia no a esperado a la respuesta de firebase te trae undefinited. Por ende, el `console.log(arreglo[0].title)` que se encuentra dentro del `ref.on` si obtiene la informacion de Firebase porque este se ejecuta luego del `arreglo.value.push`.

```
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot){
        var value = snapshot.val();
        var key = snapshot.key;
        arreglo.value.push({
          'title': value.nombre_evento,
          'start': value.fecha_inicio
         });
        console.log(arreglo[0].title) //<- Esta linea esta dentro del ref de Firebase por lo que luego de obtener los valores de Firebase
}); 
console.log(arreglo[0].title) //undefinited <- Esta linea se ejecuta sin esperar la respuesta de firebase
```

Mas info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions?hl=es-419

Espero poder haberte ayudado :D